# Hide taxonomy terms from a metabox field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hide, taxonomy

I'm trying to hide some terms from a taxonomy in a metabox field.
Original Code

```
    $premium->add_field( array(
        'name'              => __( 'Category', 'inventor' ),
        'id'                => INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX  . 'listing_category',
        'type'              => 'taxonomy_select',
        'taxonomy'          => 'listing_categories',
        'default'           => Inventor_Submission::get_submission_field_value( INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX . $post_type . '_listing_category', INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX  . 'listing_category' ),
    ) );
```

I've been trying to use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function and replace it in 'taxonomy' value but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$taxonomies = 'listing_categories';
$args = array(
    'exclude'                => array( 321, 322 ),
); 
$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    $premium->add_field( array(
            'name'              => __( 'Category', 'inventor' ),
            'id'                => INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX  . 'listing_category',
            'type'              => 'taxonomy_select',
            'taxonomy'          => $terms,
            'default'           => Inventor_Submission::get_submission_field_value( INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX . $post_type . '_listing_category', INVENTOR_LISTING_PREFIX  . 'listing_category' ),
        ) );
```

And I get this error code:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty